# iOS googlemobilevision textRecognition library swift integration

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, text-extraction, text-recognition

I could not be able to find iOS googlemobilevision textRecognition library swift integration documentation. All of their documentation are in Objective-C.i want to use googlemobilevision library for textRecognition.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMobileVision

How to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, most of the googleMobileVison libraries are available on objective C only they are not yet available in swift. But you can still use the same googleMobileVison library in the swift project.

I was having the same issue where I wanted to use googleMobileVison for face detector. You can find my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/niekzy/GoogleMobileVisionFaceDetectionDemo) where I have used objective C googleMobileVison in swift. I hope it helps. :)